# Call an intent to a specific app from WebView in android

Tags: android, android-intent, webview, android-webview

Is it possible to call an intent like `something://someone` from `WebView` and force it to open with an specific app? I don't want to open Intent Chooser when link gets clicked in `WebView`, and I want don't want it to open another app, even if that app catches `something://someone`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, no, for an arbitrary `something://someone` handled purely within HTML. You cannot prevent the user from seeing a chooser and choosing what the user wants.

That being said, you are welcome to use `WebViewClient` and `shouldOverrideUrlLoading()` with your `WebView` to detect a `something://someone` URL and do whatever you like to handle the request. This assumes that the use of `something://someone` is in a simple hyperlink.